# Stretch GridView to parent control bounds

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a custom control where I place my SemanticZoom with GridView inside.
The problem is that if GridView has only few items to display then width of the SemanticZoom is less than width of the container. As the result zoom in\out button is placed incorrectly in the middle of the screen.

If there are many items to display, then GridView stretches itself up to the parent control bounds and everything is ok.

How to stretch Semantic zoom (or inner GridView) properly even if there are only few items inside?
[image]

Custom container code:

```
<controls:DataLoader Grid.RowSpan="2" >
                <controls:DataLoader.DataContent>
                    <SemanticZoom x:Name="SemanticZoom"  Style="{StaticResource SemanticZoomStyle}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
                            ..skipped..
                        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>

                        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                            <GridView x:Name="ZoomedInView"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedPatients}}" 
                                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PatientItemTemplate}" 
                                      Style="{StaticResource DataGridViewStyle}"
                                      behaviors:SelectionChangedCommandBehavior.Command="{Binding SelectPatientCommand}" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                      Background="Yellow">


                                <GridView.GroupStyle>
                                    <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource PatientItemGroupHeaderTemplate}">
                                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </GroupStyle.Panel>
                                    </GroupStyle>
                                </GridView.GroupStyle>
                            </GridView>
                        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                    </SemanticZoom>
                </controls:DataLoader.DataContent>
```

GridView style:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridViewStyle" TargetType="GridView">
    <Setter Property="IsItemClickEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
</Style>
            </controls:DataLoader>
```

Comment: All I can say is 'Oh my gosh!'. A `DataContext` is for holding/supplying *data*, not *UI elements*... the clue is in the name. From the [`FrameworkElement.DataContext` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) page on MSDN: *Gets or sets the data context for an element when it participates in data binding*. When you do bizarre things like you have with your `DataLoader.DataContent` then all of the cards are off the table... just about anything could happen.

Comment: And by the way, the simple answer would have been to set the [`Control.HorizontalContentAlignment` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment(v=vs.110).aspx) of the parent container control to `Stretch` to make its content stretch. I wouldn't like to say if it will still work with your bizarre code though.

Comment: It is DataContent, not Context in the sample. All possible properties were set to Stretch already and it does not help.

Comment: Apologies... my bad. Still there's nothing that anyone here can do because you haven't provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can test.

Comment: How can I upload it here? Minimal example is a complete VS solution and it goes beyond the scope of copy-pasting several lines of code. I have to upload archive somewhere

Comment: Perhaps you didn't read the linked page, but it kind of starts a bit like this: *Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem*. In my multiple experiences of doing this, each time I've either been able to come up with a *small* working example of the problem, or the process of trying to reproduce the problem has enabled me to discover what the problem was and fix it myself. It's well worth doing... either you end up fixing your own problem, or you provide a *small* example that we can test and help you to fix. Really, it's a win win situation.

Comment: I red it. Even simple solution is bigger than I'm able to copy-paste here. Btw, I discovered that problem is caused by GridView. Using Grid everyting is fine.

Comment: I'm glad that you found a solution. As such, this question is of no further use to anyone, so I am going to vote to close it for being off topic with the reason *a problem that can no longer be reproduced*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution is to use Grid instead of GridView